# how to export multi table in mysql?

Tags: export, mysql

i have 10+ tables, i want to export them to another datebase. how could i do that?
i tried select * from table_a, table_b into ourfile "/tmp/tmp.data", but it joined the two tables.

Answer (score 63):

It's probably too late, but for the record:

**Export an entire database:**

```
mysqldump -u user -p database_name > filename.sql
```

**Export only one table of the database:**

```
mysqldump -u user -p database_name table_name > filename.sql
```

**Export multiple tables of the database**

Just like exporting one table, but keep on writing table names after the first table name (with one space between each name).  Example exporting 3 tables:

```
mysqldump -u user -p database_name table_1 table_2 table_3 > filename.sql
```

**Notes:**

The tables are exported (i.e. written in the file) in the order in which they are written down in the command.

All of the examples above export the structure and the data of the database or table.  To export only the structure, use `no-data`.  Example exporting only one table of the database, but with no-data:

```
mysqldump -u user -p --no-data database_name table_name > filename.sql
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you are exporting InnoDB tables on a live system, it's a good idea to use the `--single-transaction` option to ensure you get a consistent snapshot and avoid blocking other processes.

Comment: Is there a way to export only the data but not the table structure?

Comment: @Daniele - add  `--no-create-info --no-create-db` to just get the data

Answer (score 3):

Export `mysqldump -u user -p mydatabasename > filename.sql`

Import `mysql -u user -p anotherdatabase < filename.sql`